# ASP.NET - "Data at the root level is invalid" error while browsing Nuget Packages in VS 2017

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to create a .NET Web API Application and install EntityFramework using Nuget Package Manager.

But when I'm going to : **Right Click on Project References > Manage Nuget Packages > Browse** I can't find **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore** in the list.

Then I'm having this error showing at the bottom, in the output section :

`[nuget.org] Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.`

I use **VS 2017 15.5.2** and **.Net Framework 4.7.02556**.

I also get this error when using the **dotnet cli** command
`dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` :

`error:   The content at 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore'' is not valid XML.
error:   Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.`

It looks like that the dotnet cli is trying to load the remote index.json file as a XML file.

For your information, `dotnet --version` is showing `2.1.3`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the error came from the **%appdata%/Roaming/NuGet/NuGet.Config** file
There was no syntax error in this file but I just deleted it and reopened VS 2017 that created another **NuGet.Config** with less data than the deleted one.
Then the error disappeared.

Answer (score 12):

Using VS 2019, my solution was to **Clear All NuGet Cache(s)**.

This can be achieved through Options -> NuGet Package Manager -> General -> Clear All NuGet Cache(s).

Comment: Solved my issue for VS 2019.

Comment: This also worked for me. Same, VS2019

Comment: Using VS2022 and this solution still worked for me

Comment: I had this issue persistently for a few days, so today I attached to `dotnet restore -v diag` command, downloaded all symbols, added a breakpoint to where it fails and enabled the XmlException to be caught. Result: a `~\.nuget\packages\system.resources.resourcemanager\4.3.0\System.Resources.ResourceManager.nuspec` was indeed broken - a hot mess instead of XML. Note to self: check all nuspecs in this folder.

Answer (score 4):

> ASP.NET - “Data at the root level is invalid” error while browsing Nuget Packages in VS 2017

According to the error log,

> Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

It looks like an error with XML formatting in your project, such as, `web.config` or `NuGet.Config`(Path:%appdata%\NuGet). So please check your xml file for any anomalies, remove everything before `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`.

If you still could not find any anomalies in your project, please create a new blank project without any modification, then Right Click on Project References > Manage Nuget Packages > Browse, to find the package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`.

As test, I created a a .NET Web API Application project, changed the first line in the web.config file from:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`
```

To:

```
zzxml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Then open Package Manager Console, install some package with command line, I will get that error:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I opened '%appdata%\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config'. This file starts with :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
But I keep getting this error. Even when I rename the NugGet.Config file I still have the error showing. Is there any other xml file to check?

Comment: @JeremieP, how about the web.config file? Have you tried create a new project without any modification?

Comment: I created an empty ASP.NET project.
The web.config starts with <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
I did not find any syntax error, but I keep getting this error.

Comment: @JeremieP, whether this problem still exists or not, if you create a new project without any modification, after creating, Right Click on Project References > Manage Nuget Packages > Browse directly?

Comment: Just after creating a .NET Web API project (without any modification), I clicked on Project References > Manage Nuget Packages > Browse, but the error showed : "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."
It looks like that the error comes from the package source "nuget.org", because when I'm selecting another source I don't get this error.

Answer (score 1):

I just deleted file c:\Users{username}\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config and Visual Studio 2015 is working with nuget.org again.

Answer (score 1):

I had a trailing semicolon on my package source.  Removing that, and then restarting Visual Studio fixed the problem.  I had a custom `NuGet.Config` file defined in the same folder as my `*.sln`, but this also would cause issues on your `%appdata%/NuGet/NuGet.Config` path too.

[image: Trailing semicolon on package source]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My solution-specific nuget config file had a trailing "." after the nuget URL and deleting the "." fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen before when hidden characters get into the file..  Editing this file with bitbucket online editor, you can see the red dots?  These indicate some un-printable characters, that will cause the same error stated above, a corrupted nuget.config

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In My Case I have follow the below steps :

1. Repair the Visual studio 2019 using Visual studio installer app.
2. Clear all nugate cashes using Tools ==> Option ==> Nugate Package
   Manager ==> General ==> Clear All NuGage Cache(s).
3. Clean Solution and Build the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Following helped me resolving this issue.

1. Clear all nugate cashes using Visual Studio Tools ==> Option ==> Nuget Package Manager ==> General ==> Clear All NuGet Cache(s).
2. Close Visual Studio.
3. Went to my project in VS Command Prompt where the .sln file is located (i.e. C:\Projects\Project1)
4. Executed below command to restore all nuget packages:
   msbuild -t:restore
5. Open the project in Visual Studio and rebuild SOLUTION from VS.

Answer (score 0):

If you tried to clear nuget package, deleted temp/local folders like .vs and bin/obj folders and still gets the error, try to run you visual studio with administrator privileges.

Hope that helps